# Coordinates not set when using anchors in qml

Tags: qt, layout, qml, coordinates, anchor

I have faced an issue with qml which is that when I use anchors to layout items  their coordinates are not being set and are equal to zero. Please see code snippets below.

Is this behavior regular for QML anchors or it's just me doing something wrong?
How this can be circumvented?

```
Rectangle
{
    id: background
    objectName: "background"
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "#06A0D4"
}

Rectangle
{
    id: ground
    objectName: "ground"
    anchors.left: background.left
    anchors.right: background.right
    anchors.bottom: background.bottom

    color: "#D47006"
    opacity: 0.4

    height: 50;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, that it is undefined.
I suppose the problem lies within the `mapToItem`, resp. `mapFromItem` function, which needs an item as it's first argument.
I can only guess that those functions or a related one is used to calculate the coordinates, if not explicitly set.

A `Window` object is no Item, but a QQuickWindow, thus those functions won't work.

Wrap everything within an `Item` should do the trick, as now QML can calculate the positions with it's functions.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, i.e. when I run the following code in qmlscene, the text displays `Yellow rect: x=0, y=350, width=400, height=50`, which is exactly what I would have expected

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: background
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.left: background.left
        anchors.right: background.right
        anchors.bottom: background.bottom
        height: 50

        color: "yellow"

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            text: "Yellow rect: x=" + parent.x + ", y=" + parent.y +
                ", width=" + parent.width + ", height=" + parent.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try it and will let you know

Comment: This works on Mac but fails to output expected coordinates when ran on Windows